# Is there a max loud?

Tags: acoustics

Take two laptops with build-in mics and speakers.
Put them next to each other.
Turn skype on both of them, and call each other.
Laptop A should now be in a voip call with Laptop B.

Talking into either laptop microphone will output sound on both laptops.
Both laptops pickup the output sound, and output more sound.
This cycle continues, while the loudness gets more and more loud (and hurts my ears!)

Of course, this sound eventually gets to a point where the speakers can't get any louder.

If you took away the limitation of the laptop speakers, when would the loudness stop getting louder?

Comment: It seems like you're asking about your specific setup.  There is a maximum intensity where the numbers used to describe the sound saturate (usually 16-bit numbers) so the limit doesn't have to be the speakers themselves, the limit can be saturation of the numbers used to describe the volume.  I would say that the "max loud" in air is the point at which the pressure causes the air to liquefy.

Comment: It's not a question about physics, but control engineering. Although you learn the mathmatics for this in physics, the question is off topic here

Comment: ["Loudness, a subjective measure, is often confused with objective measures of sound strength such as sound pressure, sound pressure level (in decibels), sound intensity or sound power."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness)

Comment: Maybe you'd like this simpler but similar situation: when you play a guitar near the amplifier, you will hear the so called "feedback". Feedbacks are produced by the same mechanism.

Comment: you're gonna have to turn in your username if you keep asking silly stuff like this :-( .    Think about it: if you take away one physical limitation after another, at some point you'll run into the maximum air pressure level you could create without causing nuclear fusion or some other ridiculous event.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Well, no, there's a simple limit to this (+1 for DavePhD).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft No, he is taking away all control parameters, and ask for the physical limitation. Nice question in my eyes. I don't understand why you don't turn your comment in an answer? It is not obvious to everyone.

Comment: AWESOME answers guys. Thanks! Very interesting stuff!

Comment: [_These go to 11!_](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOO5S4vxi0o)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a maximum intensity sound wave for a given pressure of material.

Atmospheric pressure is 101,325 Pascals, so on the standard [decibel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) scale for sound, referenced to 20 microPascals as zero decibels, this corresponds to 194 decibels.

[Pistol Shrimp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpheidae) create sound of about this intensity with their claws!

In a higher pressure material, more intense sound is possible.  Sound waves in stars have been considered.  Perhaps neutron stars, or quark stars if they exist, would have the highest maximum intensity sound waves.

Comment: That animal is kinda interesting.

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat *very* interesting! :O